# Map a triple join table with @MapKeyJoinColumn

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, join, mapkeyjoincolumn

I have 3 entities named : "Movie", "Person" and "Role", a person has a certain role in a movie.

In my database, i have these 3 entities and to link them, a table :
**Cast(id_movie,id_person,id_role)** all primary, because a person can be for example producer and actor.

So far in my entity Movie I wrote this to make the link :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "distribution",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_movie"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_role"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_pers")
private Map<Person,Role> list_cast = new HashMap<Person,Role>();
```

But of course it doesn't work because key in a map is unique.
So list_cast[person] gives me the only the last role.

Comment: I think i have to keep it because we'll need to add Role in the future, otherwise I would have make table such as Actor

Comment: Essentially what you want then is private Map<Person, List<Role>> roles; which is unfortunately not supported in JPA. As far as I can see you  will need to map as a Set or whatever and transform to a Map<Person, List<Role>> in memory once loaded.

Comment: Okay so in order to keep this database design I have to drop JPA ?